# What is UILocalNotification repeatCalendar used for and how is it used

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have created a `UILocalNotification` I would like to know how ever what `repeateCalendar` can be used for?

This is my simple implementation of a `UILocalNotification`.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// Set the fire date/time
[localNotification setFireDate:dateFromString];
[localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

// Setup alert notification
localNotification.alertTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Reminder (%@)", amPm];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is my alertBody"];
localNotification.userInfo = identificationDict;
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
//localNotification.repeatCalendar = what do I put here? and why;

localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[localNotification setHasAction:YES];
app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Currently [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatCalendar) say

> The calendar the system should refer to when it reschedules a
>   repeating notification

However no discussion on why you would use it? In theory could I use it to define Weekday and Weekends?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the most widely used calendar - Gregorian calendar, there are a few other calendars, for example in China, we have a Chinese calendar (*NSCalendarIdentifierChinese*) which is totally different from the Gregorian calendar. We use that calendar for our traditional holidays and astronomical dates. So if the users are mainly Chinese, then you probably need to set `repeatCalendar` to Chinese calendar, otherwise your notification might fire on the wrong date. Here is the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/) from Apple talking about all different kinds of calendars.